# Sorting list in a page and it's child page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have javascript that is finding the current page url and sorting a list on it. The same list is found on a child page. For example the parent page is Criminal Law, but it also has multiple children pages: Assault, Menacing, Domestic Violence, and so on. The child pages are not getting the list sorted alphabetically and I really have no idea how to do it. I was hoping I could get some ideas of how to do this. I'm still pretty new at javascript.

```
var currentPage = document.URL;
    if (currentPage == "http://www.jbplegal.com/criminal-law/") {

var items = $('#gb-simple-page-hierarchy-5 ul li').get();
items.sort(function(a,b){
  var keyA = $(a).text();
  var keyB = $(b).text();

  if (keyA < keyB) return -1;
  if (keyA > keyB) return 1;
  return 0;
});
```

HTML Unordered List Code

```
<aside id="gb-simple-page-hierarchy-5" class="widget gb-page-hierarchy-widget"><h1 class="widget-title"><a href="http://www.jbplegal.com/criminal-law/">Criminal Defense Attorneys</a></h1><ul><li><a href="http://www.jbplegal.com/criminal-law/assault-and-menacing/">Assault and Menacing</a></li><li><a href="http://www.jbplegal.com/criminal-law/felonies/">Charged with Felonies</a></li><li><a href="http://www.jbplegal.com/criminal-law/child-abuse-child-endangerment/">Colorado Child Abuse</a></li><li><a href="http://www.jbplegal.com/criminal-law/controlled-substances/">Controlled Substances</a></li><li><a href="http://www.jbplegal.com/criminal-law/criminal-mischief/">Criminal Mischief</a></li><li><a href="http://www.jbplegal.com/criminal-law/criminal-record-sealing/">Criminal Record Sealing</a></li><li><a href="http://www.jbplegal.com/criminal-law/domestic-violence/">Domestic Violence</a></li><li><a href="http://www.jbplegal.com/criminal-law/failure-to-appear/">Failure to Appear</a></li><li><a href="http://www.jbplegal.com/criminal-law/felony-drug-charges/">Felony Drug Charges</a></li><li><a href="http://www.jbplegal.com/criminal-law/harassment/">Harassment</a></li><li><a href="http://www.jbplegal.com/criminal-law/juvenile-delinquency/">Juvenile Delinquency</a></li><li><a href="http://www.jbplegal.com/criminal-law/marijuana-related-offenses/">Marijuana-Related Offenses</a></li><li><a href="http://www.jbplegal.com/criminal-law/minor-in-possession/">Minor In Possession</a></li><li><a href="http://www.jbplegal.com/criminal-law/misdemeanor-charges/">Misdemeanor Charges</a></li><li><a href="http://www.jbplegal.com/criminal-law/protection-orders/">Protection Orders</a></li><li><a href="http://www.jbplegal.com/criminal-law/sex-offenses/">Sex Offenses</a></li><li><a href="http://www.jbplegal.com/criminal-law/theft-charges/">Theft Charges</a></li><li><a href="http://www.jbplegal.com/criminal-law/trespass/">Trespass</a></li></ul></aside>
```

Comment: I suggest you sort the list as it is delivered to the page

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could just use `items.sort()`
in your code to automatically let JavaScript sort it in order for you after appending all the values of the pages children into another list.

For example,

```
var values = [];
for (var i=0; i < items.length;i++) {
    values.append($(items[i]).text())
}
values.sort()
// Sorted values "Assault", "Domestic Violence", etc.
```

The only other workaround would be to use a library which allows for robust sorting of lists.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
// Get to the list and the items
var list = document.querySelector(".gb-page-hierarchy-widget ul");
var listItems = document.querySelectorAll(".gb-page-hierarchy-widget ul li a");

// Set up the variables
var i,j,li;
var arrItems = [];

// Loop through all the list items, creating an array of the text content
// followed by a ~ which represents the current position in the list
// Set a data-i attribute containing the current position in the list
// on the link (<a>) tag
for (i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
   arrItems.push(listItems[i].textContent + '~' + i );
   listItems[i].setAttribute("data-i",i);
}

// Let JavaScript sort the array
arrItems.sort();

// Loop through the sorted array
for (i = 0; i< arrItems.length; i++) {
    // Discard the text, leaving only the current position of the
    // item in the list
    j = arrItems[i].replace(/^.*~/, '');
    // Get the parentNode (li) of the link
    li = document.querySelector('[data-i="'+j+'"]').parentNode;
    // Remove the list item (li) from the list
    list.removeChild(li);
    // Append the removed item to the end of the list
    list.appendChild(li);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found something that works great! With some searching on the internet and a little modification I was able to get this to work:

```
var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
var newPage = pathArray[1];
```

This would sort the list on the parent page and also any child page of that parent.